# Send multiple contact form from one page via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have 3 contact form in one page ( Header, Body, Footer ). The code works correctly if sent from one form. I want to use one AJAX request for all forms. That is, when you click on the submit button, so that the code checks if this form then send data to php. How can i do it right? I use the `hasClass ()` method of jquery, but I have errors in the console

**HTML:**

***Footer Form***

```
<form id="contact-form1" method="POST" class="d-flex form">
    <input type="text" class="simple-input" id="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" class="simple-input" id="email" placeholder="Email address">
    <textarea class="quession-input" id="msg" placeholder="Your question"></textarea>
    <div class="checkboks custom-sq">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checked-checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" id="box1" checked="checked" value="true" />
        <label for="box1" class="checkboks-text"><?php echo the_field('checkbox_text', 'option'); ?></label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="danger-btn submit1"><?php echo the_field('btn_send', 'option'); ?></button>
</form>
```

***Another Form***

```
<form id="contact-form" method="POST" class="d-flex form">
    <input type="text" class="simple-input" id="hy_name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" class="simple-input" id="hy_email" placeholder="Email address">
    <textarea class="quession-input" id="hy_msg" placeholder="Your question"></textarea>
    <div class="checkboks custom-sq">
        <input type="checkbox" id="box3" class="checked-checkbox" checked="checked" />
        <label for="box3" class="checkboks-text"><?php echo the_field('checkbox_text', 'option'); ?></label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="danger-btn hy-submit submit2"><?php echo the_field('btn_send', 'option'); ?></button>
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.hasClass('submit1')) {
        var name = jQuery('#name').val();
        var email = jQuery('#email').val();
        var msg = jQuery('#msg').val();
        var subj = jQuery('#subj').val();    
        var data =  "action=send_email&name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&msg=" + msg + "&subj=" + subj + "&myCheckboxes=" + choice,    
    } elseif (e.hasClass('submit2')) {
        var hy_name = jQuery('#hy_name').val();
        var hy_email = jQuery('#hy_email').val();
        var hy_msg = jQuery('#hy_msg').val();
        var data =  "action=send_email&name=" + hy_name + "&email=" + hy_email + "&msg=" + hy_msg + "&myCheckboxes=" + choice,  

    }
    validateEmail(email);
    if (msg == '' || email == '' || validateEmail(jQuery('#email').val()) == false) {
        validateEmail(email);
        validateText(jQuery('#msg'));
        validateText(jQuery('#name'));
        return false;
    }

            var chkElem = document.getElementsByName("myCheckboxes[]");
            var choice ="";

            for(var i=0; i< chkElem.length; i++)
            {
                if(chkElem[i].checked)
                    choice = choice + chkElem[i].value;
            }

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: data;
        success: function (response) {
            jQuery('#contact-form input').val('');
            jQuery('#contact-form textarea').val('');
            jQuery('.submit').text('Done!');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
    });

});
```

**PHP:**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_email', 'send_email');
add_action('wp_ajax_send_email', 'send_email');
function send_email() {

    $checkbox = $_POST['myCheckboxes'];
    if (isset($checkbox)) {
        echo $checkbox;
    }
    $headers = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"';
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $hy_name = $_POST['hy_name'];
    $from = 'contact@xelon.ch';
    $to = 'yaver.mammadov@gmail.com';
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $hy_email = $_POST['hy_email'];
    $msg = $_POST['msg'];
    $hy_msg = $_POST['hy_msg'];
    $subject = 'Footer form: ' . $_POST['email'];
    $message .= (!empty($name)) ?  '<p><strong>User Name</strong> : ' . $name .'  </p>' : '';
    $message .= (!empty($email)) ?  '<p><strong>User Email</strong> : '. $email .'</p>' : '';
    $message .= (!empty($msg)) ?  '<p><strong>User Message</strong> : '.$msg .'</p>' : '';
    $message .= (!empty($checkbox)) ?  '<p><strong>Checkboxs</strong> : '.$checkbox .'</p>' : '';
    $message .= '</body></html>';
    echo mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    return  $msg;
    die();
}
```

Comment: ___but I have errors in the console___ WHat errors, please show us

Comment: An `id` in html has to be UNIQUE on the page, you are using `id="submit"` for both buttons

Comment: @RiggsFolly But how do I do it right? You can not use one id? but when pressed checked from what form is sent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `serialize()`, and use a class to identifique buttons submit. Using two identical ids on one page is not good practice.
If you use the class `.submit` per example in each button submit:

```
$('.submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).closest('form').serialize();

    [...]
}
```